# Why are block level elements in this page displaying inline?

Tags: html, css, block

I have met my wit's end. If anyone can tell me why the block level elements (h3 and p tags) are displaying inline in this page, you will be my hero: http://www.emc2017.emcss.org/committee-members

Comment: Because of the display flex: `.content {display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}`  
You can read more about the display flex here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: Please include the code in your question, as soon as that site changes, it ceases to be a valid example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I should've caught that - much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.content` has `display: flex;` on it, affecting the children even though they are set to `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `display: flex` on the parent element `.content`